# How can i fix error LNK 2022?

Tags: c++, c++-cli

I have a simple library that I made on C++/CLI just for testing:

```
#pragma once
using namespace System;       
namespace ClassLibrary2 {
    public ref class Class1
    {
       public:int ReturnInt()
       {
        return 40;
       }
    };
}
```

It works good, when i'm adding it as a reference to my C# application. But when i'm adding in a code `#include <Windows.h>` string after the `#pragma once` string, error LNK 2022 became:

```
MSVCMRT.lib(mstartup.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131195) : Custom attributes are not consistent: (0x0c0001e2).
MSVCMRT.lib(mstartup.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131195) : Custom attributes are not consistent: (0x0c0001e6).
MSVCMRT.lib(managdeh.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131195) : Custom attributes are not consistent: (0x0c0000c0).
MSVCMRT.lib(managdeh.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131195) : Custom attributes are not consistent: (0x0c0000c2).
MSVCMRT.lib(mehvecdtr.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131195) : Custom attributes are not consistent: (0x0c0000a6). 
MSVCMRT.lib(mehvecdtr.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131195) : Custom attributes are not consistent: (0x0c0000a9). 
MSVCMRT.lib(ManagedMain.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131195) : Custom attributes are not consistent: (0x0c0000bf). 
MSVCMRT.lib(ManagedMain.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131195) : Custom attributes are not consistent: (0x0c0000c1). 
MSVCMRT.lib(msilexit.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131195) : Custom attributes are not consistent: (0x0c0000e9). 
MSVCMRT.lib(msilexit.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131195) : Custom attributes are not consistent: (0x0c0000ec). 
MSVCMRT.lib(pureMSILcode.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131195) : Custom attributes are not consistent: (0x0c000199). 
MSVCMRT.lib(pureMSILcode.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131195) : Custom attributes are not consistent: (0x0c00019a). 
LINK : fatal error LNK1255: link failed because of metadata errors
```

How can I fix it ?

Comment: Please post the complete error message; also: I cannot reprodcue this.

Comment: Any clues in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909470/lnk2022-error-when-using-clr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I throw from the answer of PazO of this
[question:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571546/clr-cli-linker-fails-with-error-lnk2022-custom-attributes-are-not-consistent)

So in final i just installed visual studio 2008 and add `#include <Windows.h>` string after the `#pragma once` string and now it's perfectly work for me!